# Json validator schema throws a com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.ProcessingException exception

Tags: mule, mule-studio

**I have the following validator:**

`<json:validate-schema schemaLocation="C:/Users/NameOfUser/Documents/Project/FilesProject/jsonSchema.json" doc:name="Validate JSON Schema"/>`

**The content of the file is this**

`{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Root schema.",
  "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
  "properties": {}
}`

**When I compile mule throws the following exception:**

ERROR 2016-06-14 09:49:04,191 [main] org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry: Failed to shut down registry cleanly: org.mule.Registry.Spring
org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "dispose" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@1f3c5308
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:248) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextDisposePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextDisposePhase.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistryLifecycleManager$SpringContextDisposePhase.applyLifecycle(SpringRegistryLifecycleManager.java:141) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.dispose(AbstractRegistry.java:68) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker$2.onTransition(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker$2.onTransition(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:64) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryBrokerLifecycleManager.fireDisposePhase(RegistryBrokerLifecycleManager.java:82) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.dispose(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:137) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.dispose(DefaultMuleContext.java:345) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager.doDispose(TransactionalQueueManager.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.queue.AbstractQueueManager.dispose(AbstractQueueManager.java:109) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager.dispose(DelegateQueueManager.java:83) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 35 more
INFO  2016-06-14 09:49:04,191 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Closing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@13cd7ea5: startup date [Tue Jun 14 09:48:58 ART 2016]; root of context hierarchy
ERROR 2016-06-14 09:49:04,395 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.ProcessingException: fatal: URI scheme "c" not supported (URI: "c:/Users/LBonaventura/Documents/DataWareHouse/ArchivosQuickplay/jsonSchema.json#")
    level: "fatal"
    scheme: "c"
    uri: "c:/Users/LBonaventura/Documents/DataWareHouse/ArchivosQuickplay/jsonSchema.json#"

```
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.URIManager.getContent(URIManager.java:96) ~[json-schema-core-1.2.4.jar:?]
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.SchemaLoader$1.load(SchemaLoader.java:115) ~[json-schema-core-1.2.4.jar:?]
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.SchemaLoader$1.load(SchemaLoader.java:109) ~[json-schema-core-1.2.4.jar:?]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527) ~[guava-18.0.jar:?]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319) ~[guava-18.0.jar:?]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282) ~[guava-18.0.jar:?]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197) ~[guava-18.0.jar:?]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937) ~[guava-18.0.jar:?]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941) ~[guava-18.0.jar:?]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824) ~[guava-18.0.jar:?]
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.SchemaLoader.get(SchemaLoader.java:172) ~[json-schema-core-1.2.4.jar:?]
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonValidator.buildJsonSchema(JsonValidator.java:210) ~[json-schema-validator-2.2.5.jar:?]
at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory.getJsonSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:224) ~[json-schema-validator-2.2.5.jar:?]
at org.mule.module.json.validation.JsonSchemaValidator$Builder.loadSchema(JsonSchemaValidator.java:194) ~[mule-module-json-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.json.validation.JsonSchemaValidator$Builder.build(JsonSchemaValidator.java:169) ~[mule-module-json-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.json.validation.ValidateJsonSchemaMessageProcessor.initialise(ValidateJsonSchemaMessageProcessor.java:36) ~[mule-module-json-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.routing.MessageProcessorFilterPair.initialise(MessageProcessorFilterPair.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.initialise(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.processor.AbstractMuleObjectOwner.initialise(AbstractMuleObjectOwner.java:72) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.routing.Foreach.initialise(Foreach.java:206) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.processor.AbstractMuleObjectOwner.initialise(AbstractMuleObjectOwner.java:72) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.routing.Foreach.initialise(Foreach.java:206) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.routing.MessageProcessorFilterPair.initialise(MessageProcessorFilterPair.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.initialise(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:317) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:241) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.construct.Flow.doInitialise(Flow.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:97) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistry.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:116) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.jar:?]
```

INFO  2016-06-14 09:49:04,397 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'trackingetl' never started, nothing to dispose of
ERROR 2016-06-14 09:49:04,596 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'trackingetl', see below       +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ProcessingException: fatal: URI scheme "c" not supported (URI: "c:/Users/LBonaventura/Documents/DataWareHouse/ArchivosQuickplay/jsonSchema.json#")
    level: "fatal"
    scheme: "c"
    uri: "c:/Users/LBonaventura/Documents/DataWareHouse/ArchivosQuickplay/jsonSchema.json#"

```
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:197) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.jar:?]
```

Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Could not initialise JsonSchemaValidator (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Could not initialise JsonSchemaValidator (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 14 more

Answer (score 1):

To specify a Windows relative path, use the backslash \, for example \temp specifies C:\temp if Mule resides in drive C:\

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the first time i tried with the backslach \ but in that case mule throws a exception that i can understant:  Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\name\Documents\Project\FilesProject\jsonSchema.json.  For that reason i change the backslashes to the regular slashes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mule Docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/json-schema-validator#schema-redirects), Schema Location should be an URI. You are passing a filePath.

The best option is to set your schema inside your resources folder and link it like this:
resource:/jsonSchema.json